# Want to execute a script irrespective of the directory where this script is present or html file is present

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

Actually my script is present under the path `/home/user/bin/script.sh` and when I run the above script named as script.sh, the script will show html file in Firefox web page.

But the problem here is when I run this script from the directory which is having this html file only it is working but it is not working from any other directory.
The command used to run the script is:

```
/path/to/script.sh /path/to/html file
```

Also when I run the script from any other directory, the web page shows the content of that particular directory. Suppose let's see
I run the command from the directory/home`/user/Manu/archave`, it is displaying the content which this archave directory is having in the web page.
Please find the content of script.sh file

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0 /home/egajash/arch/index.html"
   exit 1
fi

HTML_PATH="$1"
PORT_FILE=".chosen_port"
function find_free_port() {
    for port in {8100..8110}; do
      if ! nc -z -v -w5 localhost $port 2>/dev/null; then
       echo $port
       return
      fi
    done
}
if [ -e "$PORT_FILE" ]; then
  PORT=$(cat "$PORT_FILE")
fi
if [ -z "$PORT" ] || nc -z -v -w5 localhost "$PORT" 2>/dev/null; then
  PORT=$(find_free_port)
  echo "$PORT" > "$PORT_FILE"
fi
function stop_server() {
  local port="$1"
  local pid=$(lsof -t -i:$port)
  if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
    kill "$pid"
  fi
}
function monitor_browser() {
  local browser_pid
  while true; do
    browser_pid=$(pgrep -f "Firefox.*$PORT")
    if [ -z "$browser_pid" ]; then
      echo "Web browser closed. Exiting..."
      stop_server "$PORT"
      exit
    fi
    sleep 1
  done
}
stop_server "$PORT"
if [[ -n $PORT ]]; then
  python3 -m http.server $PORT &
  firefox "http://localhost:$PORT" &
  echo "Server is running on port $PORT. This script will automatically close when the web browser is closed."
  monitor_browser
else
  echo "No free port available."
fi
```

Comment: Custom scripts behavior depends on their code and unless you show us the contents of your `script.sh` file, we can't suggest any solution.

Comment: Hi, please find content of script.sh file provided above.

Comment: Getting as server.py: error: argument port: invalid int value: '/home/user/pmfiles/web' Path of html file is /home/user/pmfiles/web/index.html Path of the script is /home/user/bin/script.sh Path from where this script is run is /home/user/Manu/archave In the web page getting as "Unable to connect"

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `$HTML_PATH`, but you're never using it.

Try:

```bash
python -m http.server --directory "$(dirname "$HTML_PATH")" $PORT
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801718/how-to-run-a-http-server-which-serves-a-specific-path)